# Are all private keys required to create a multisig bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

Do all 3 private keys in a 2-of-3 multisig wallet have to exist on the same device at some point in order to generate the bitcoin address?

It would be ideal if the 3 private keys never existed on the same device together but it seems the examples I've found assume all 3 exist simultaneously when generating the bitcoin address and redeem script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need **private** keys at all to **generate** multisig m-of-n address!

You do need **public** keys. Yes, three for m-of-3 and eleven for 5-of-11 (for example)